# Как поменять кодировку в JS-файле?

Tags: кодировка, html, javascript

Есть [сайт](http://enternet-agency.ru/).

На сайте есть счётчик обратного отсчёта справа, в голубом поле,
после заголовка "Мы - ENTERNET - маркетинговое агентство...".

В этом счётчике текст отображается некорректно.

Как можно исправить ситуацию? Как поменять кодировку js-файла?

Comment: Подозреваю, что проблема связана с тем в какой кодировке сохранён сам js файл. Забудьте про `charset="windows-1251"`. Откройте этот проблемный файл в каком-либо редакторе (AcelPad, Notepad, Ms VS :) ) и пересохраните его в `utf-8, без BOM`

Comment: А если в nginx в локации server стоит charset windows-1251 то хоть прописано script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" всё равно пойдёт в windows-1251 :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В заголовке страницы

```
<meta name="http-equiv" content="Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

При объявлении скрипта

```
<script src="" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

В .htaccess

```
AddCharset utf-8 .js
```

Вместо utf8 устанавливайте свою кодировку.

Answer (score 1):

Укажите нужную кодировку через атрибут charset, например так:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="windows-1251" src="http://domain.ru/js/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: никаких win-1251, только utf-8!!!..

Answer (score 0):

Указывайте только **charset="utf-8"**, в дальнейшем избежите проблем. Этим вы говорите скрипту в какой кодировки внутри будут все отрабатывать.

К примеру вы указали `<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://domain.ru/js/script.js"></script>`, и если вы даже укажите в .htaccess -> AddCharset windows-1251 .js  и `<meta name="http-equiv" content="Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1251">` в заголовке страницы.

Скрипт все равно отработает в utf-8